# PHP Error (Undefined offset: 1) when using chrome to download a file

Tags: php, undefined, offset

I have a PHP script to manage download (VIP users can download only)
The script works with common download managers and browsers (Like firefox, IE, IDM & edge) , but I'm getting this error when I want to use chrome to download file:

Undefined offset: 1 in /home/username/public_html/index.php on line 103

Line number 103:
list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);

```
    //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
    if($is_resume && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);

        if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
        {
            //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
            //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
            list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }
    }
```

I've tried some of codes that I found here in stackoverflow topics, but not working!

```
list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig);

list($range, $extra_ranges) = array_pad(explode(',', $range_orig, 2), -2, null);

list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig. ',');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra ranges are optional.

Basically, `explode(',', $range_orig, 2)` gets you either an array of one value (when there is only one range) or an array of 2 values (when there are at least 2).

You can use [`array_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) before `explode` to pad `null` to your array onto that second index. You've tried that but used a negative index, which makes your array `[null, <first_range>]` instead of `[<first_range>, null]`.

So, change your code to this:

```
list($range, $extra_ranges) = array_pad(explode(',', $range_orig, 2), 2, null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the error has gone with your code, but download with chrome still fails and there is no errors in log file!
Can you help how can I find the problem?

Comment: @RezaFH This is a different issue then, you should post another question and be as specific as you can with what you attempted.